# PayU: Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstname() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/local/Gfgrisales/Payu/Model/Payu.php on line 120

Tags: magento-1.9, php, third-party-module

I recently install the PayU plugin downloaded from the PayU website. After installing the plugin my website is working fine and also I have the payment options on the checkout page for PayU payment but when I select payment option as "PayU" I get following errors:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstname() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/local/Gfgrisales/Payu/Model/Payu.php on line 120

I tried to look at the code at line number 120 in file Payu.php and it looks like this:

```
$params = array(
    'merchantId'            =>      $merchant_id,
    'referenceCode'         =>      $orderIncrementId,
    'description'           =>      $ProductName,
    'amount'                =>      $paymentAmount,
    'tax'                   =>      $tax,
    'taxReturnBase'         =>      $taxReturnBase,
    'signature'             =>      $signature,
    'accountId'             =>      $account_id,
    'currency'              =>      $currency,

    'buyerFullName'         =>      $order->getShippingAddress()->getFirstname().' '.$order->getShippingAddress()->getLastname(),
    'buyerEmail'            =>      $order->getCustomerEmail(),
    'shippingAddress'       =>      $order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet1().' '.$order->getShippingAddress()->getStreet2(),
    'shippingCity'          =>      $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity(),
    'telephone'             =>      $order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone(),

    'payerFullName'         =>      $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname().' '.$order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname(),
    'billingAddress'        =>      $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet1().' '.$order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet2(),
    'billingCity'           =>      $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity(),
    'payerPhone'            =>      $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone(),

    'test'                  =>      $test,
    'confirmationUrl'       =>      Mage::getUrl('payu/payment/notify'),
    'responseUrl'           =>      Mage::getUrl('payu/payment/success'),
    'extra1'                =>      $extra1,
    //'gateway_url'         =>      $gateway_url,
);
```

as I am newbie in Magento and PHP i can't find how to fix the above issue. Also it will be great if someone can explain that why this issue happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error message, it seems that `$order->getShippingAddress()` is not an object : this is why you get this error.

You will have to find why your order does not have a shipping address.

If you look `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php:getShippingAddress()`, the method can return an object $address but it can also return `false`. In your case, it seems that the return is `false`.